# Sound extracting/processing in python

Tags: python, wav, librosa

So recently i wanted to get heands on sound classification using NN and I've found this tutorial :

[aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-09-03-urban-sound-classification-part-1/](http://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-09-03-urban-sound-classification-part-1/)

Unfortunately code seems not to work properly in some areas.

At first:

```
def load_sound_files(file_paths):
raw_sounds = []
for fp in file_paths:
    X,sr = librosa.load(fp)
    raw_sounds.append(X)
return raw_sounds
```

couldn't load one of 10 example files meant later to be ploted.
I wrote a short script to check how many files there are that cannot be read, and it turned out to be around 40% of first fold!
So I read a bit on web, tried out other libraries for reading and ended up with this:

```
def load_sound_files(file_paths):
raw_sounds = []
sffreq = []
for fp in file_paths:
    X,sr = soundfile.read(fp)
    #X=np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(X),dtype=np.float64)
    sffreq.append(sr)
    try:
        #if stereo sound compress to mono
        Z = np.compress([False, True], X, axis= 1)
        Z+= np.compress([True, False], X, axis= 1)
        X = (Z/2.0).flatten()

    except:
        pass
    raw_sounds.append(X)
return raw_sounds, sffreq
```

This seems to open all the files, however it outputs slightly different values than librosa, and in some cases plots differ a lot. 
Mostly it's fine but in case of gunshot:

> [image: Gunshot waveform]
>   Gunshot Waveform

---

> [image: Gunshot specgram]
>   Gunshot Spectrogram

They differ a lot.

It also seems that librosa opened every wav as mono with frequency of 22050, whereas soundfile opened most of the files as stereo, some as mono, with different frequencies, depending on sound file.

And here comes the first question:

Why is it so?

Why does the read data differ as well as mono/stereo data and frequencies?

How can I determine which data is more accurate?

Later on i tried code for feature extraction and i ended up with this, rather long crash report occurred on tonnetz function:

```
def extract_feature(file_name):
    X,sample_rate = sf.read(file_name)
    #X=np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(X),dtype=np.float64)
    try:
        print ("Freq of sf: ", X.shape)
        Z = np.compress([False, True], X, axis= 1)
        Z+= np.compress([True, False], X, axis= 1)
        X = (Z/2.0).flatten()

    except:
        print "Wow i had one dim"
    stft = np.abs(librosa.stft(X))
    mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T,axis=0)
    chroma = np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
    mel = np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(X, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
    contrast = np.mean(librosa.feature.spectral_contrast(S=stft, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
    tonnetz = np.mean(librosa.feature.tonnetz(y=librosa.effects.harmonic(X), sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
    return mfccs,chroma,mel,contrast,tonnetz


<ipython-input-14-29f39c0472e8> in <module>()
      2 
      3 sub_dirs = ['fold1','fold2','fold3']
----> 4 features, labels = parse_audio_files(parent_dir,sub_dirs)

<ipython-input-13-97fd78a13282> in parse_audio_files(parent_dir, sub_dirs, file_ext)
     22     for label, sub_dir in enumerate(sub_dirs):
     23         for fn in glob.glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, sub_dir, file_ext)):
---> 24             mfccs, chroma, mel, contrast,tonnetz = extract_feature(fn)
     25             ext_features = np.hstack([mfccs,chroma,mel,contrast,tonnetz])
     26             features = np.vstack([features,ext_features])

<ipython-input-13-97fd78a13282> in extract_feature(file_name)
     15     mel = np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(X, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
     16     contrast = np.mean(librosa.feature.spectral_contrast(S=stft, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
---> 17     tonnetz = np.mean(librosa.feature.tonnetz(y=librosa.effects.harmonic(X), sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
     18     return mfccs,chroma,mel,contrast,tonnetz
     19 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/feature/spectral.pyc in tonnetz(y, sr, chroma)
   1155 
   1156     if chroma is None:
-> 1157         chroma = chroma_cqt(y=y, sr=sr)
   1158 
   1159     # Generate Transformation matrix

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/feature/spectral.pyc in chroma_cqt(y, sr, C, hop_length, fmin, norm, threshold, tuning, n_chroma, n_octaves, window, bins_per_octave, cqt_mode, mode)
    934                                       bins_per_octave=bins_per_octave,
    935                                       tuning=tuning,
--> 936                                       real=False))
    937 
    938     # Map to chroma

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/constantq.pyc in cqt(y, sr, hop_length, fmin, n_bins, bins_per_octave, tuning, filter_scale, aggregate, norm, sparsity, real, resolution)
    249 
    250         # Compute the cqt filter response and append to the stack
--> 251         cqt_resp.append(__cqt_response(my_y, n_fft, my_hop, fft_basis))
    252 
    253 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/constantq.pyc in __cqt_response(y, n_fft, hop_length, fft_basis)
    529 
    530     # Compute the STFT matrix
--> 531     D = stft(y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, window=np.ones)
    532 
    533     # And filter response energy

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/spectrum.pyc in stft(y, n_fft, hop_length, win_length, window, center, dtype)
    165 
    166     # Window the time series.
--> 167     y_frames = util.frame(y, frame_length=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length)
    168 
    169     # Pre-allocate the STFT matrix

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/util/utils.pyc in frame(y, frame_length, hop_length)
    100     # Horizontal stride is `hop_length` samples
    101     y_frames = as_strided(y, shape=(frame_length, n_frames),
--> 102                           strides=(y.itemsize, hop_length * y.itemsize))
    103     return y_frames
    104 

/home/dziobak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.pyc in as_strided(x, shape, strides, subok, writeable)
    100         interface['strides'] = tuple(strides)
    101 
--> 102     array = np.asarray(DummyArray(interface, base=x))
    103 
    104     if array.dtype.fields is None and x.dtype.fields is not None:

/home/dziobak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I honestly have no idea what's going on out there and would appreciate some help.

Comment: were you able to get the notebook working end-end? I am also facing issues in encode method

Comment: Unfortunately not, I wrote a whole new project basing on spectrograms, didn't care about tonnetz and etc as it seems those features dont really let CNN get better scores